# Check if Column Exists and drop using Vertica

Tags: exists, alter, vertica

fWe have a HP Vertica database and I am writing some scripts that will be eventually deployed in GIT to make changes to my dimensional model.  As a part of general house keeping in the first few lines I will have some code that will remove the elements being modified in the script which all seems very straigh forward.

Here is an example of the sort of thing I am using, and it works.

```
DROP CONSTRAINT if exists fk_fctClick_Money_SourceKey


DROP TABLE if exists SCHEMA.dimSourceType
```

I am a bit stuck on how to achieve this code when checking to see if a column exists.  Seems straighforward in most other database's but I cannot find anything on how to do this in Vertica.

I know in PostgreSQL it looks a bit like this:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.dimSourceTypeS DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS SourceKey;
```

This doesn't work as the error says there is an error near word "EXISTS".  The MSSQL counterparts does not work either.

Can anyone help me on this query please?

Comment: You can query the `columns` table to see if the column exists. Vertica does not have  `IF EXISTS`

Comment: Hi @Kermit, thank you for your response. IF EXISTS does work on the sample's I have provided within Vertica (drop a table or constraint) however its just with removing a column that I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use "IF EXISTS" since it is not supported.  Pl see [doc here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/ALTERTABLE.htm)

You can loop through the columns of table of interest or each table and run alter table on existing columns only.

With something like below using your favorite language:

```
for a given table
   set_of_existing_cols = get("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM columns WHERE table_name = <YOUR_TABLE>")
   set_of_delete_columns = set_of_existing_columns intersect set_of_columns_you_want_to_delete
   for each column from set_of_delete_colmn
      run("ALTER TABLE <YOUR_TABLE> DROP COLUMN column")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query to get all col names from all tables of that schema :

```
select table_schema,table_name,column_name,data_type from v_catalog.columns where select table_schema,table_name,column_name,data_type from v_catalog.columns limit 1 like '%table_name% ;
```

from the result of this query which is generally a list of list [[a,b,c,int]]
then you can look up and see if that col was present.

for dropping:

```
alter table table_name drop column col_name;
```